# send orgmode sh babel block to eshell/term in emacs?

Tags: org-mode

Does anyone know if its possible to send the bash code in a orgmode sh block and run in in a new eshell/term buffer in emacs?
for example as a use case i would like to run/eval a code block like this

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
sudo pacman -Syuu
#+END_SRC
```

and have the command execute within emacs in term, eshell etc?

is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to send the current line or selected region to the shell associated with a given buffer:

```
(defun kdm/sh-send-line-or-region () 
(interactive)
(if (use-region-p) 
  (append-to-buffer (get-buffer (directory-shell-buffer-name)) (mark)(point))
  (let (p1 p2)
    (setq p1 (line-beginning-position))
    (setq p2 (line-end-position))
    (append-to-buffer (get-buffer (directory-shell-buffer-name)) p1 p2)
  ))
  (let (b)
    (setq b (get-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window (get-buffer (directory-shell-buffer-name)))
    (execute-kbd-macro "\C-m")
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window b)
    )
  )

(global-set-key "\M-s" 'kdm/sh-send-line-or-region)
```

Comment: thx. i tried it and get the following error ```get-buffer: Symbol's function definition is void: directory-shell-buffer-name```. any clue?

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps that is defined by my shell, which is configured with: `(use-package shell-current-directory
  :bind ("M-S" . shell-current-directory)
  :config (load-file (expand-file-name "shell.el" user-emacs-directory))
  )`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply execute some commands then write them in the source block and execute using `C-c C-c` while in the block.
To execute on a remote machine or as sudo combine use of `:dir` and tramp,   For example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /sudo:pacman@localhost:
who am i
date
#+END_SRC
```

reference

- https://orgmode.org/manual/Environment-of-a-Code-Block.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Usage.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways this could be done. The most straight forward at the time of writing is probably to use a session:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :session *my-shell*
sudo pacman -Syuu
#+END_SRC
```

This will create a new comint process (like with `M-x shell`) called "*my-shell*". Blocks whose header specifies the session will be executed in that shell. If you wanted to interact with it outside of Org, you can switch to it in the buffer list.